# Session unique on taking new tab in IE7

Tags: asp.net, sessionid

I provide sessionstate in my web.config file like this

sessionstate mode="InProc" cookieless="UseUri

That way each tab generates a new unique session ID in the URL with the format like this :
http://www.domain.com/(S(kbusd155dhzflbur53vafs45))/default.aspx

It worked, but when I copy the url and paste it on another tab then the previous session value is inheriting. How can I solve this issue? Is there anyother method to solve issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution to this situation would be issue a ticket (guid or seomthing like that) in each response you write to the client. In the request the client would send this ticket and the server would 1) Check to see if it is valid and 2) Invalidate it so just one request (the original one) could be made with it. This way your user wouldn't be able to take advantage of new tabs or even copy/paste of URLs.

Comment: But In this case I have to issue ticket in all my pages, right?

Answer (score 0):

If the user pastes a URL containing an existing session token into a new tab, your application cannot possibly know that this is a new tab and not an existing tab.  I'm afraid that short of some hacky browser plugin there isn't much you can do about this.

Comment: It will create security threats to the system and since my project is based on a banking system, it causes a big issue.

Comment: What kind of attack are you anticipating here?

Comment: Do you find anyother solution to avoid this unique session id in these multitab browsers otherthan managing it in web.config file

Comment: when a user login to the system and he receives a mail with a link which is used for activating another account which has already been activated in the system(this account will be having an id). When the link is clicked then the page will open in the next tab. At this time, the user goes to his previous tab which has another account. Automatically the new session id of the user new user will get active in this account and he can access the rights of the previous user